# Django, having Q object filter by users full_name

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

I have a simple search box that searches for posts(filters post) by title, first_name, last_name, however no matter how hard I try I am not able to search by users full_name

In my models I have

`User.full_name = property(lambda u: u"%s %s" % (u.first_name, u.last_name))`

In my terminal `Django Shell` I get the below results

```
>>> user.first_name
'Blake'
>>> user.last_name
'Lively'
>>> user.full_name
'Blake Lively'
```

Now when I try searching with the users full_name I get the below error

> Related Field got invalid lookup: full_name

```
Q(user__full_name__icontains=query)
```

Below are my views

```
class QList(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Question
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
    template_name = 'questions/all_questions.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_questions'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QList, self).get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) | #This works
                Q(user__username__iexact=query) | #This works
                Q(user__first_name__iexact=query) | #This works
                Q(user__last_name__iexact=query) | #This works
                Q(user__full_name__icontains=query) #This Fails what am I doing worng

                )
        return queryset
```

> ### Tried this

```
class QList(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Question
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
    template_name = 'questions/all_questions.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_questions'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QList, self).get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if ' ' in query:
            query = query.split()
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                chain(User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[0], last_name__icontains=query[1]),
                      User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[1], last_name__icontains=query[0])))

            return queryset
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__username__iexact=query) |
                Q(user__first_name__iexact=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

                )
        return queryset
```

**Getting error**

> argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
if ' ' in query:
```

Comment: Can you show model User. If its only property, you cant filter backend it

Comment: @NgocPham Its the django default user model

Comment: Ivan's answer in the [question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688826/django-having-q-object-filter-by-function-in-model) provides exactly what you need (even the field names are the same). What problems do you have with that approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, having Q object filter by function in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688826/django-having-q-object-filter-by-function-in-model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `filter()` with a property like that is not possible, for filter to work it must be a model field.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property) thread to see some possible workarounds using managers or annotations.

Edit for the new error:

Your `query = self.request.GET.get('q')` is returning `None` when there is no `q`, and you can't check for something in None. Change that line to `query = self.request.GET.get('q', '')` so if there is no `q`, it defaults to the empty string.

Comment: Do you think you type a workaround that would work around my code.  I looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688826/django-having-q-object-filter-by-function-in-model. But could not integrate it to my code

Comment: @MarcoBianchi i updated my answer taking into account the new error

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @gdef_  The below code did the job

```
class QList(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Question
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
    template_name = 'questions/all_questions.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_questions'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QList, self).get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)

        if query:
            queryset = queryset.annotate(
                full_name=Concat(
                    'user__first_name',
                    Value(' '),
                    'user__last_name',
                    output_field=CharField()
                )
            ).filter(
                Q(full_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__username__iexact=query) |
                Q(user__first_name__iexact=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

                )
        return queryset
```